# How do I account for the extra elements at the end of an array if it is shorter in the next iteration of a nested loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I've got a nested for loop, in the inner loop I've got an array that will change size and value in each iteration,e.g;

```
a=[ 2 3 4]
```

and in the next iteration it will be :

```
a=[9 5]
```

but the result of my code is :

```
a=[9 5 4]
```

a(3) is the problem, it is from the previous iteration and I don't want it,so what should I do?

I do not know how to write my code here cause it contains lots of functions and you wont understand it!?

but it's sth like this:

```
for j=1: 5
%l is the length of row in cell array(a) that varies from one row to another
for i=1:l
 dn=a{j,i};
spp(t)=dn(1)
end
 targ{j,1}=spp;
end
```

spp is the problem here

Comment: Though the problem seems to be solved already, please post a working example next time. It will make it much easier for people to help you if they can just copy paste the example code and see the problem happening without having to adjust anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `clear` command to delete the temporary variable (once `spp` have three elements, it never goes back to a 2 elements vector unless you clear it or declare it).

```
...
targ{j,1}=spp;
clear spp;
...
```

Alternatively, you can code the matlab-way by declaring your variable before it gets populated. In this situation, there is no need for a clear command.

```
for j=1:5

    %l is the length of row in cell array(a) that varies from one row to another
    spp = zeros(1,l);
    for i=1:l
    ...
```

Comment: @SaraDean Especially if you know what size the variable is going to be it is recommended to declare (initialize) it, rather than clear it. This way memory allocation can be done more efficiently.